# Rust Nested Serde Lifetimes?

Tags: rust

How does one nest serde-izable structs? I tried the simplest approach and the compiler complained about a lifetime not even in my program (`'de`).

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct A<'a> {
    symbol: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum B<'a> {
    A(A<'a>),
}
```

```
   Compiling rust_iex_parser v0.1.0 (...filename...)
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/test.rs:8:21
   |
8  | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'de` as defined here...
  --> src/test.rs:8:21
   |
8  | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/test.rs:8:21
   |
8  | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `EnumAccess<'_>`
              found `EnumAccess<'de>`
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/test.rs:9:8
   |
9  | enum B<'a> {
   |        ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/test.rs:10:7
   |
10 |     A(A<'a>),
   |       ^
   = note: expected `<A<'a> as Deserialize<'_>>`
              found `<A<'_> as Deserialize<'_>>`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Deserialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: This is probably worth a read: [Understanding deserializer lifetimes](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html). Having a lifetime for a `Deserialize`-able struct means that it is bound to the life of the deserialization source, so you should consider whether that's actually what you want. In most cases you probably want to use a `String` and avoid lifetimes entirely.

Comment: In this example, how does one use a String to avoid lifetimes entirely?

Comment: `symbol: String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For field types other than `&[u8]` and `&str`, that involves lifetimes, you have to annotate them with `#[serde(borrow)]`. See [Understanding deserializer lifetimes - Borrowing data in a derived impl](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#borrowing-data-in-a-derived-impl):

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct A<'a> {
    symbol: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum B<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    A(A<'a>),
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e36554f155fb19bcb2231a480b6c5f3).